# Does somebody know about this tool?

Tags: simulation, electrical

I'm very proud to be a part of this community. I'll be very thankful,if somebody does recongnize this simulation tool? (Please see image)
Thank you very much for your help.[image: Workspace]

Comment: Redact?  .........

Comment: Smells like Quartus or Labview, or maybe even simulink. FYI you're question has nothing to do with Electronic Design. Also, you're breaking some [rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). I look forward to seeing you in the future when you got an actual Electronic Design question.

Comment: Simulink was my first guess but it doesn't quite match the style or the program panels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Ascet for model based software development.

[Advanced Simulation and Control Engineering Tool](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCET)

Comment: Thank you very much all of you! I consider this problem as being solved. I apologize, if I did break some rules when posting my question. I will try to stick to them next time. Thanks!